# How can I have Microsoft Teams notification pop up at more noticeable place?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-teams

I changed to a 38 inch monitor. One problem is, MS Teams notification always pops up at the right hand side corner, because the screen is so big, I very often miss it.

Is there a way I can have the notification pop up in the middle of the task bar? Or somehow make it more obvious?

I turned off sound, but if it is the only option, I guess I will have to turn in on. Mostly I am looking for visual effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a Teams notification, or a Windows 10 Toast notification?

Answer (score 0):

MS teams don't provide this kind or personalization. Maybe it would be help if you could change the status bar position,  due this notification functionality depends on the operative system, in Linux or Mac os for example the status bar is located on the bottom.

Comment: Although I think you're correct that MS teams doesn't directly allow this kind of personalisation. However, there might be other solutions. Perhaps even relocating all notifications (if the OP accepts). Please try and get more information from the OP and update your answer accordingly.